# Flutter - Full screen CircularProgressIndicator

Tags: flutter, layout

In Flutter i try to call a web service to retrieve some data. When service works fills a list and show it on screen. I want to show a CircularProgressIndicator in full screen when if data is null (or trying to get data from service). Now CircularProgressIndicator is on the top on the page.

The code is

```
  Scaffold(
            body: Column(children: <Widget>[
              SafeArea(child: progress),
              loading == false ? rssi : indicator
            ]),



   final indicator = Container(
        child: Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
        valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.black),
      ),
    ));
```

I want to show 'indicator' widget below 'progress' widget on the whole screen.

Any help?

Comment: Look into this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58277766/flutter-create-an-overlay-progress-bar/58281225#58281225

Answer (score 2):

You can create a common ProgressIndicator widget like this,

```
class ProgressDialogPrimary extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var brightness = MediaQuery
        .of(context)
        .platformBrightness == Brightness.light;
    ;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(AppColors.themeColorSecondary),
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: brightness ? AppColors.colorWhite.withOpacity(
          0.70) : AppColors.colorBlack.withOpacity(
          0.70), // this is the main reason of transparency at next screen. I am ignoring rest implementation but what i have achieved is you can see.
    );
  }
}
```

Then do something like this

```
Scaffold(
 body: isLoading
          ? ProgressDialogPrimary()
          : Column(children: <Widget>[
...
]
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I changed the code too: backgroundColor: brightness
          ? Colors.white.withOpacity(0.70)
          : Colors.black.withOpacity(

Comment: the components work nicely.  I replaced my overlay code because the debug complained it was outside the framework

Answer (score 1):

This works. Just tested on Dartpad:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: loading == false ? Text("loaded") : Container(
          constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
          child: CircularProgressIndicator()
        )
      )
    );
  }
```